# Sort Different Documents in ElasticSearch DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have three types of documents indexed in ElasticSearch: `Car`, `Bike`, and `Truck`. I've written a query to retrieve all the documents that match a particular criteria but I also want to sort the order by which the `Car`s are retrieved using only a property that the `Car` has and is not found among a `Bike` and `Truck`.

So far this is what I have:

```
   {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "is_registered": true
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "ac_type": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

But I am getting an error on `Bikes` that do not have the property `ac_type`.

```
"type": "query_shard_exception",
"reason": "No mapping found for [bike.ac_type] in order to sort on",
```

How can I retreive all three document types but only sort according to fields that appear in a single document?

Index Mapping for car:

```
{
    "car": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "event": {
                "properties": {
                    "ac_type": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1549617583913",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "cuwdmQbBTLeaSpkvzW4kPw",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6030299"
                },
                "provided_name": "car"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your index mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is add 'ac_type' parameter in all the documents. For the car you can add values for this param and for others don't add any value. This value you can sort the document which has data and for others, it won't matter.